# jQuery not working in IE AHHH?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My website I am making for a client is here : http://vicewebdesign.com/resonantlight_com/

It works perfectly in chrome and firefox but in IE non of the plugins (jquery) work, There are 3 diff jquery plug ins, the home page hre has a nivo slider not working in IE : http://vicewebdesign.com/resonantlight_com/

The tabify plugin foron this pag isnt working in IE :http://vicewebdesign.com/resonantlight_com/perl

and also on the same page the quovolver plug in isnt working.

I have searched this alot and all the ansers I find are specific to a plug in and my prblem is NONE of my jquery is working. I tried diff library code script like differnt versions and all and latest. But nothing working !

Comment: I can't say for certain that it has to do with your problem, but you include jQuery twice. There's a link to a copy of jQuery 1.7 on google APIs, and then a copy of an earlier version of jQuery hosted in your site.

Comment: @HackedByChinese is right, you include jQuery twice. First the 1.7.2 + some plugins (tabify, nivo, ...) and after that 1.4.4 version. This  kills at least the first jQuery version including the plugins in IE. jQuery itself should work with IE 6+ (not quite sure if 5.5+ as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that IE9 is now adhering to standards and this gives problems with plugins trying to circumvent the pre IE9 problems.

One possible solution is to force IE9 in IE8 standards mode with this meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"></meta>
```

the other option is to fix the code:

most UI plugins reside on `$.browser.msie` to check if we are in IE but they don't check the version. In my case the solution (jquery.ui.checkbox.js) was to replace all `$.browser.msie` calls with this variable :

```
var isIEAndVersionIsLowerThan9 = $.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9);
```

This solution is better than adding the meta tag as it will enable all IE9 features.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem in IE, solution suggested by @whorsdaddy worked for me perfect, it should work for u also. best luck.

Comment: When I look in IE none of it works... hmm the nivo slider isnt sliding, the quvolver is showing all quotes and not rotating and the tabify plugin, just goes to that spot on the page when you click on a tab instead of hiding them from view instead of clicked on.

Comment: I put in that meta codd and Its working now THANKS !!!!!! it was so weird because nivo was working on a different site in IE but not on this one, along with all other jquery its working now !

Comment: @pythonian29033: don't get overexcited. If you need to add the meta tag, it means that some javascript is not compatible with IE9. See this as a temporary workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Try this this will works

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"></meta>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>jQuery from Microsoft AJAX CDN</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="btn">Show Message</button>

        <div id="message" style="display:none">

            <h1>Hello from jQuery!</h1>

        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Fallback to loading jQuery from a local path if the CDN is unavailable
            (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>'));
        </script>
        <script>

            function domReady() {
                $('#btn').click( showMessage );
            }

            function showMessage() {
                $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
            }

            $( domReady );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```